# Recibir un FormData en un Api Rest C#

Tags: c#, api, rest, fetch, formdata

Estoy trabajando con React con (Fetch) y estoy trabajando el Backend en un Api Rest C#

Estoy intentando enviar un FormData que contiene algunos datos string y un archivo, a mi Api y a pesar de que el FormData contiene data, en el Api me llega todo Null, estuve buscando información pero no logre poner mi proyecto a funcionar.

en React lo tengo asi...

El archivo lo obtengo así.

```
<input color='primary' type="file" name="file" onChange={changeHandler} />
```

changeHandler

```
  const changeHandler = (event) => {
setSelectedFile(event.target.files[0]);}
```

El fetch

```
    var myHeaders = new Headers();
myHeaders.append("Accept", "application/json");
myHeaders.append("Content-Type", "application/json");
myHeaders.append("Authorization", "Bearer " + localStorage.getItem("accessToken"));

const formData = new FormData();
formData.append('attachment', selectedFile);
formData.append('Subjet', Subjet);
formData.append('emailTo', EmailTo);
formData.append('emailMessage', EmailMessage);

var requestOptions = {
  method: 'Put',
  headers: myHeaders,
  body: formData
};

fetch(apiEmails, requestOptions)
  .then(response => {
    if (response.status === 200) {
      response.json()
        .then(result => {
          if (result === true) {
            alert("Correo enviado correctamente");
          }
        })
      setLoading(false);
    }
    else {
      setShowMessageError(true)
    }
  })
  .catch(error => {
    setShowGeneralError(true)
  })
```

En el BackEnd me entra en el controlador, pero el objeto **mail** trae todos sus atributos **Null**

```
        [HttpPut("SendEmail")]
    public GeneralResponse SendEmail([FromForm] Mail mail)
    {
        try
        {
            var result = _emailsDetailsServices.SendEmail(mail);
            HttpContext.Response.StatusCode = StatusCodes.Status200OK;
            return new GeneralResponse() { StatusCode = 0, Data = result };
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            _logger.LogError("EmailsController - SendEmail {error}", e.Message);
            _logger.LogError("EmailsController - SendEmail {error}", e.InnerException);
            throw new Exception("Ocurrió un error inesperado al hacer la consulta intentelo nuevamente.");
        }
    }
```

El modelo **Mail** esta construido de la siguiente forma...

```
    public class Mail
{
             public string Subjet { get; set; }
             public string EmailTo { get; set; }
             public string EmailMessage { get; set; }
             public List<IFormFile> Attachment { get; set; }
}
```

cualquier ayuda es agradecida.

Comment: Ojo con las mayusculas y minusculas en los nombres en tu c#!!!! se tienen que llamar exactamente igual, y aca no pasas

Comment: Ya escribi igual los nombres y aun llega null la data

Comment: Si te llega null tal vez ni siquiera esta ingresando ya hiciste debug y ver si esque por lo menos ingresa al metodo?

Comment: si, ya hice un get del formData en el lado del cliente y esta la info, y en el controller del backend puse un breakpoint para analizar el objeto que llega y vienen los atributos null

Answer (score 0):

Espero que hayas resuelto tu problema. Según veo estás estableciendo el tipo de contenido como application/json sin embargo este es un 'Content-Type: multipart/form-data'. Prueba eso, saludos